# How to load additional packages with R::rticles?

Tags: r, workflow, rnw, stata

I mostly code in R, and have been using knitr Rnw for a while, mostly following the best practices outline in 14mech14's YouTube [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrWBHqN3TUE), with a parent rnw document, child rnw document, and a document for my R code and all the tables / figures.

I recently started experimenting with Rmd for my journal articles using the rticles package, but just ran into the issue of having to load new packages into the Rmd document. I have seen Yihui's [document](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-extra.html), but it doesn't seem to work if I have

```
output: rticles::aea_article
extra_dependencies: ["rotating"]
```

How do I solve this issue? (Moreover, if I have colleagues that work in STATA, how do I enable them to work on the paper as well? Should I just write everything in Latex itself and export?)

Here is my .Rmd file:

````
---
title: "BLAH"
month: "`r format(Sys.Date(), '%m')`"
year: "`r format(Sys.Date(), '%Y')`"
author:
  - name: Myself
    firstname: Nobody
    surname: Owens
    email: nobody.owens@blob.edu
    affiliation: some institute of technology
acknowledgements: |
  Thank you to my humble research assistant for his research assistance.
abstract: |
  This is the abstract.

output: rticles::aea_article
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
# this R code imports my data from the .R file: (of course for this online example I don't have a file to show)

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE)

# IMPORT PACKAGES-------------
list.of.packages <- c("dplyr", "data.table","ggplot2", "kableExtra", "tinytex", "stargazer")
new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"])]
if (length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)
for (package in list.of.packages) {library(eval((package)), character.only = TRUE)}

# LOAD THE DATA FROM THE .R FILE---------
# load(".RData")
```
Blah blah blah...

This works, because it's a small table.

```{r, echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
# some table with kableExtra package:
# just an example...
a <- data.frame(a = c("orcs","orcs","elves", "elves", "elves"), b = c(1,2,3,4,5), c = c(1,2,3,4,5))

a %>% kbl(
  .,
  booktabs = TRUE,
  linesep = "",
  caption = "Model Summary Statistics",
  label = "meansd"
) %>%
  kableExtra::column_spec(column = 2:3, width = "0.5in") %>%
  kableExtra::collapse_rows(columns = 1,
                            valign = "middle",
                            longtable_clean_cut = FALSE) %>%
  kable_styling(
    font_size = 4,
    latex_options =
      c("hold_position",
        "condensed")
  )
```

But what if I have a big one...?


\begin{table}[!htbp]\centering
\caption{My Regressions}
\label{tab:nobodyowensregressions}
```{r, results = "asis"}

# this is some code from my original .R file that gets saved into the .RData file:

panelfit <- list()
for (i_ in c(1:10)){
panelfit[[i_]] <- lm(b~c, data = a)
}

model.smmrys.tex <- 
  R.utils::captureOutput(
    stargazer(
      panelfit,
      type="latex",
      font.size = "footnotesize",
      style = "aer",
      float = FALSE,
      column.sep.width = "-12pt",
      df = FALSE,
      dep.var.labels = "",
      dep.var.caption = ""
    )
  )

cat(model.smmrys.tex, sep = "\n")

```
\end{table}
````

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do something like \begin{sidewaysfigure}, \end{sidewaysfigure} before and after the table. Landscape doesn't work here because AEA is twosided. Do I just have to edit the base .Tex file? (I'm fine with that, but was hoping for an Rmd solution).

Note: You have to have the AEA cls file from the rticles package in the same directory as this Rmd document in order for this to run.

Note2: I have posted on the rticles [Github page](https://github.com/rstudio/rticles/issues/371)

**I just found out this question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31503418/how-to-add-a-latex-package-to-r-journal-template-from-rticle-package-in-r)**

Comment: When I use R in my research I usually just export the figures and tables that I want to include in a paper to LaTeX using `xtable` or `ggplot2`, and write the paper itself fully in LaTeX. But I guess this is opinion based, so I'll vote to close.

Comment: Note: if it indeed gets closed then one way to reopen it is to remove the "what is your workflow" part and focus on the specific practical issue of how to use additional packages using `rticles`.

Comment: Thanks, just did that. How do I reopen?

Comment: @maxIRimp Editing to get an objective question was the best thing to do.  The only thing now is to wait for enough people to vote to reopen.

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I voted to reopen as well. To make it easier to answer/more likely to get an answer you could improve the question a bit further, by including a small example Rmd document that people can run and that produces the issues that you have. That saves the trouble of trying to recreate the issue from scratch, and it also ensures that proposed solutions actually apply to your setup.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I ended up doing. I found out my question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31503418/how-to-add-a-latex-package-to-r-journal-template-from-rticle-package-in-r).

````
---
title: "BLAH"
month: "`r format(Sys.Date(), '%m')`"
year: "`r format(Sys.Date(), '%Y')`"
author:
  - name: Myself
    firstname: Nobody
    surname: Owens
    email: nobody.owens@blob.edu
    affiliation: some institute of technology
acknowledgements: |
  Thank you to my humble research assistant for his research assistance.
abstract: |
  This is the abstract.

output: rticles::aea_article

header-includes: 
 - \usepackage{graphicx} # THIS REALLY IS THE KEY HERE
 - \usepackage{rotating}
 - \usepackage{pdflscape}
 - \usepackage{dpfloat}
 - \usepackage{biblatex}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
# this R code imports my data from the .R file: (of course for this online example I don't have a file to show)

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE)

# IMPORT PACKAGES-------------
list.of.packages <- c("dplyr", "data.table","ggplot2", "kableExtra", "tinytex", "stargazer", "R.utils")
new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"])]
if (length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)
for (package in list.of.packages) {library(eval((package)), character.only = TRUE)}

# LOAD THE DATA FROM THE .R FILE---------
# load(".RData")
```
Blah blah blah...

This works, because it's a small table.

```{r, echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
# some table with kableExtra package:
# just an example...
a <- data.frame(a = c("orcs","orcs","elves", "elves", "elves"), b = c(1,2,3,4,5), c = c(1,2,3,4,5))

a %>% kbl(
  .,
  booktabs = TRUE,
  linesep = "",
  caption = "Model Summary Statistics",
  label = "meansd"
) %>%
  kableExtra::column_spec(column = 2:3, width = "0.5in") %>%
  kableExtra::collapse_rows(columns = 1,
                            valign = "middle",
                            longtable_clean_cut = FALSE) %>%
  kable_styling(
    font_size = 4,
    latex_options =
      c("hold_position",
        "condensed")
  )
```

But what if I have a big one...?


\begin{sidewaystable} # AND THEN YOU CAN EDIT THE RMD FILE LIKE SO
\caption{My Regressions}
\label{tab:nobodyowensregressions}
```{r, results = "asis"}

# this is some code from my original .R file that gets saved into the .RData file:

panelfit <- list()
for (i_ in c(1:10)){
panelfit[[i_]] <- lm(b~c, data = a)
}

model.smmrys.tex <- 
  R.utils::captureOutput(
    stargazer(
      panelfit,
      type="latex",
      font.size = "footnotesize",
      style = "aer",
      float = FALSE,
      column.sep.width = "-12pt",
      df = FALSE,
      dep.var.labels = "",
      dep.var.caption = ""
    )
  )

cat(model.smmrys.tex, sep = "\n")

```
\end{sidewaystable}
````

Comment: It's great that you found an answer, but link-only answers on a different site aren't really that helpful to others. And there are numerous answers to that question. Could you summarize what you did to get things working and add it as an answer here. Thanks!

Comment: thanks, just edited!

Comment: +1 thanks a lot!